# Get value from textarea input in event object

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with a textarea where users can put comments, and then trigger a onClick (when the form is submitet via the button).However, I cant get the value of the input, for example if a user writes "test", I want it to get into the handleSubmit function.

My form

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
    <label>Skicka</label>
    <textarea placeholder="Type in comments (allergis etc.)" name ="name" ref ="name"></textarea>

    <button className="btn" type="submit">
        Send
    </button>
</form>
```

//my handler

```
public handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.name.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the textarea value separately in the onChange method of the textarea like this (for class component):

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
   method="POST"

   >
    <label>Skicka</label>
    <textarea
         onChange={this.setComments}
         placeholder="Type in comments (allergis etc.)"
         name="name"
         value={this.state.comment}/>

<button className="btn" type="submit">
    Send
</button>
</form>   
// The save function
const setComments = e => this.setState({comment: e.target.value});
```

This will save the textarea input in your local state and you can access it in your submit function with this.state.comment.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: you can also directly call the setState() on text area on change event, like `onChange ={e=> this.setState({comment: e.target.value})`

Comment: But for class components, that's bad practice, because it creates a new function on every render.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by changing the handleSubmit method. Check below updated method.

```
public handleSubmit = event => {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(event.target.name.value)
}
```

But if you are work with React application then update the state variable via onChange event.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using [`Uncontrolled Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). You can make use of [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get value.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.refs.name.value)
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4gdrht)

**Note:** In React you should never add `method="POST"` and `action` attribute's on `form`.

Don't add `public` keyword to your function (if you are not using typescript).

Better approach to work with form values, is [`Controlled Component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)